# Can you take out a common factor when taking a derivative of a vector function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors

For example, if you have a tangent unit vector

T(t) = $\langle $$\sqrt{2}\over e^{7t}+e^{-7t}$, $e^{7t}\over e^{7t}+e^{-7t}$, $-e^{-7t}\over e^{7t}+e^{-7t}$$\rangle$

and you want to find its derivative, could you factor out $1\over e^{7t}+e^{-7t}$ to get

T(t) = $1\over e^{7t}+e^{-7t}$$\langle $$\sqrt{2}$, $e^{7t}$, $-e^{-7t}$$\rangle$

and then take the derivative of the interior term by term and the factor to get

T'(t) = $1\over 7e^{7t}-7e^{-7t}$$\langle $$0$, $7e^{7t}$, $7e^{-7t}$$\rangle$?

Any advice as to take a derivative of a vector such as this in an easier way would be welcome.

...or is brute forcing a derivative of these kinds of vectors simply inevitable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can pull out the factor. But when you do, because the factor depends on $t$, you'll have to use the (usual) product rule to compute the derivative:

$$\frac{d}{dt} [f(t) \cdot \vec{v}(t)] = \frac{d}{dt}f(t) \cdot \vec{v}(t) + f(t) \frac{d}{dt}\vec{v}(t)$$

---

In this case,

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{1}{e^{7t} + e^{-7t}} \left\langle \sqrt{2}, e^{7t}, -e^{-7t}\right\rangle\right] =\\ \frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{1}{e^{7t} + e^{-7t}}\right] \left\langle \sqrt{2}, e^{7t}, -e^{-7t}\right\rangle + \frac{1}{e^{7t} + e^{-7t}} \frac{d}{dt}\left\langle \sqrt{2}, e^{7t}, -e^{-7t}\right\rangle $$

$$= \frac{1}{7e^{7t}-7e^{-7t}}\left\langle \sqrt{2}, e^{7t}, -e^{-7t}\right\rangle + \frac{1}{e^{7t} + e^{-7t}} \left\langle 0, 7 e^{7t}, 7 e^{-7t}\right\rangle$$

Comment: You missed a negative sign on the exponential of z component of the vector in the last term written. (should be $7e^{-7t}$). 

Other than that, great explanation! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Sunsprint Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: By the way, does the vector $T(t)$ really have unit length?

Comment: $T(t)$ should have unit length, as it's defined as $\frac{r(t)}{|r'(t)|}$, which should yield a unit length vector, though I didn't verify it personally. I just got this instance of $T(t)$ by doing my professor's generated problem haha